# Abstract algebra (Homomorphism)

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a subring of $S$. Prove that the function $$f:R \to S$$  defined by $f(x)= x$ for all $x \in R$ a homomorphism. Is it injective? surjective ?

I have no idea how i could answer this question?

I need your help..

Comment: Can you give your defintions of a ring and a ring homomorphism? Do you know any characterizations for injectivity? Do you know any examples of rings and maybe subrings?

Comment: As a reality check, it's always good to try to say in plain words what the morphism is doing. In your opinion, what is $f$? Given this plain formulation, can you intuitively say if $f$ is injective and/or surjective? And if not, what is the reason? If you can do all this, giving a formal proof should be pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Use the definition of homomorphism:

$f: R \to S$ is a homomorphism if and only if
$$ f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y) $$
and
$$ f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$$
for all $x,y \in R$.

Answer (score 0):

It's always helpful to write down the definitions of the things you're working with. What's a ring homomorphism? What's an *injective* ring homomorphism? What's a *surjective* ring homomorphism? What's a subring?

When checking surjectivity, you may have to check two different cases, the case what $R$ is a proper subring (so $R\neq S$) and then the case when $R$ is equal to $S$.

I'll show how to do one small part of this question. The rest I'll leave to you.

Suppose $R=S$ and $f\colon R\to S$ is given by $f(x)=x$ for all $x\in R$. I claim that $f$ is surjective (this will not be the case if $R\neq S$ - show this). Let $y$ be in $S$. We need to find an $x$ in $R$ such that $f(x)=y$. Well, by the definition of $f$, we can pick $y=x$ and, because $R=S$, we also know that $y\in R$, hence there exists an $x$ in $R$ such that $f(x)=y$. It follows that $f$ is surjective.

Now you should try to show that $f$ is injective, and if $R\neq S$, then $f$ is **not** surjective. You should also show that $f$ is a homomorphism directly from the definition.